# Using a DateTime as paramter in stored procedures, conversion failed

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have created a stored procedure that takes a single `DATETIME` as its input parameter. When I try to pass in a date in the format of `MM-DD-YYYY` OR `YYYY-MM-DD` I get the error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

The date I am testing with is `2010-01-01` and if I take that and plug it right into the select statement from the stored procedure it woks fine. What do I have to do to use a `DATETIME` as a parameter?

Here is my code:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.WSL_ProjectSearchByDate
    @param1 DATETIME --Search Date
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @STMT NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @STMT =
        'SELECT project AS Project,
                project_desc AS Description
                status_gl AS Status
        FROM dbo.PJPROJ WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE crtd_datetime >= ' + @param1 + '
        OR lupd_datetime >= ' + @param1 + ';';
```

EDIT: I am fully aware this is not best practice to be using dynamic SQL, I don't have any say in the matter and this question is not about the merits of dynamic SQL and whether or not I should be using it. This is how I have been instructed to build my stored procedures and so I am doing that.

Comment: Why are you using dynamic sql? from what code are you executing the stored procedure?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Because I have been instructed by the experts to do it this way. The proc will eventually be called by a VB.Net Web Service but right now I am just testing via SSMS and the `EXEC` statement.

Comment: The code you presented does not requires the use of dynamic sql, so unless there is more sql then you are showing I doubt the so called experts really knows their stuff. anyway, .Net datetime maps directly to sql server datetime so you really don't need to worry about format.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I am 100% aware it does not need dynamic SQL but I just do as I am told in this case. I know .Net datetime maps but in testing passing in this test case is failing and I would like to know why.

Comment: The "experts" need some push back.  Simply put, dynamic sql is the wrong approach here.

Comment: @DMason I would gladly put you in touch with Microsoft on this and let you tell them so.

Comment: I stand by my comment: dynamic sql is the wrong approach here.  Regardless of whether or not it is your choice, if you are compelled to continue down that path, Chris's answer below should suffice (despite the down vote).  Something tells me you're not exactly happy with the cards you've been dealt.  Good luck with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the parameter type to `VARCHAR` and add quotes to your dynamic SQL:

```
...
@param1 VARCHAR(10) --Search Date
...
WHERE crtd_datetime >= ''' + @param1 + '''
OR lupd_datetime >= ''' + @param1 + ''';';
```

or -

Apply a `CONVERT` to your parameter when constructing your dynamic SQL:

```
...
WHERE crtd_datetime >= ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @param1, 120) + '''
OR lupd_datetime >= ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @param1, 120) + ''';';
```

Comment: Updated, think you need to change parameter type to `VARCHAR` also.

Comment: I don't want to use a `VARCHAR` as the input parameter though. This question is about getting a `DATETIME` parameter working.

Comment: You can either accept a `VARCHAR` parameter, or explicitly `CONVERT` your `DATETIME` parameter to a `VARCHAR` when creating your dynamic SQL.

Comment: Is that not unnecessary conversations? Take a string in and convert to DateTime or take a date time and convert to string the to datetime again.

Comment: Well, if you **must** use dynamic sql... yes!

Comment: Ok, if it is a restriction because I have to use dynamic SQL I will make the change and test out. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Various settings (language, date format) only influence how the `DateTime` is shown to you in SQL Server Management Studio - or how it is parsed when you attempt to convert a string to a `DateTime`.

There are many formats supported by SQL Server - see the [MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Most of those formats are **dependent** on what settings you have - therefore, these settings might work some times - and sometimes not.

The way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

If you use SQL Server 2008 or newer and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

The recommendation for SQL Server 2008 and newer is to use `DATE` if you only need the date portion, and `DATETIME2(n)` when you need both date and time. You should try to start phasing out the `DATETIME` datatype if ever possible.

So in your concrete case, try this:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.WSL_ProjectSearchByDate
    @param1 DATETIME2(0) --Search Date 
    -- @param1 DATETIME2(0) -- or use this, if you really only care about DATE - no time portion
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        project AS Project,
        project_desc AS Description
        status_gl AS Status
    FROM 
        dbo.PJPROJ 
    WHERE 
        crtd_datetime >= @param1
        OR lupd_datetime >= @param1;
```